# Mulesoft remove object from an array

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I would like to add values that get from an external http call to the payload, but before I should remove the objects from the array, I tried to use the reduce function but the result are not what i expected.

The payload looks like this

```
[
    {
    "foo": "bar"
    },

    {
    "bar": "foo"
    }
]
```

the value i am getting from the http call is an array :

```
[
  {
    "ssrCode": "x1",
    "ssrdescription": "main client"
  },
  {
    "ssrCode": "x2",
    "ssrdescription": "authorized"
  }
]
```

the final result should be just the objects into the original payload

```
[{
    "foo": "bar"
},
{
    "ssrCode": "x1",
    "ssrdescription": "main client"
},
{
    "ssrCode": "x2",
    "ssrdescription": "authorized"
} {
    "bar": "foo"
}
]
```

The below reduce add all the same objects to the same {} instead of separate

```
payload reduce ((v, acc = {} ) -> acc ++ v)

{
  "ssrCode": "x1",
  "ssrdescription": "main client",
  "ssrCode": "x2",
  "ssrdescription": "authorized"
}
```

Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

Ugo your post is a bit confusing to begin with.

Did you try to just concatenate the two arrays together?  You can concatenate arrays with the `++` function: e.g. `payload ++ vars.httpCallResult` where the variable `httpCallResult` is added in here for illustration purposes.

If you provide more details I should be able to add more details on my end.

Comment: Hi George, thanks I tried that but it doesn’t works, since I need the http results without the [ ] of the array

Comment: What is your expected output then? I don't see any issue on the output of reduce.

Comment: Should be:

[{
    "foo": "bar"
},
{
    "ssrCode": "x1",
    "ssrdescription": "main client"
},
{
    "ssrCode": "x2",
    "ssrdescription": "authorized"
} {
    "bar": "foo"
}
]

Comment: You are just concatenating the two arrays then, do you want to have the `ssrCode` records sandwich between the `foo` and the `bar`?

Comment: So you want to create a single object out of all the objects in the array, correct?  If so the `reduce` you provided should work as long as all records are in the array.  Another way you can get it done (assuming the `httpCallResult` is defined as before) is by doing the following `{(payload ++ vars.httpCallResult)}`

Comment: No, reduce doesn't works because of instead of 2 objects, it reduces to just one , also ++ concatenate an array to the object so i will enda up with [ {...}, [   {...}, {...}   ] ] instead of [ {...}, {...}, {...} ]

Comment: `++` will give you single array not an array of arrays.  If you are getting an array of arrays you are doing something wrong elsewhere

Comment: As what George have mentioned ++ will join two arrays. So you will end up with [{..},{..},{..},{..}]. However if you expected it to be {{..},{..},{..}}, this is not a valid json object and I don't think it is possible.